# Generate JSON from tree structured database

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework, yii, tree

im building an gallery app and i need it to be in tree format , im using the jstree extension to build it , and i need the json to be in this format:

```
$(function () {
    $("#demo1").jstree({ 
        "json_data" : {
            "data" : [
                { 
                    "data" : "A node", 
                    "metadata" : { id : 23 },
                    "children" : [ "Child 1", "A Child 2" ]
                },
                { 
                    "attr" : { "id" : "li.node.id1" }, 
                    "data" : { 
                        "title" : "Long format demo", 
                        "attr" : { "href" : "#" } 
                    } 
                }
            ]
        },
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui" ]
    }).bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) { alert(data.rslt.obj.data("id")); });
});
```

and im using this database:

categorys:
id
name
id_father

products:
id
name
price
category_id

please help me guys , >_< , im  using an MVC structure in my project and its possible to do things like  foreach(modelinstance as model) ...

help i realy need it and i have no idea how to build it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the function that I use, youll need [CNestedSetBehavior](http://yiiext.github.com/extensions/nested-set-behavior/index.html) in your model though, I recomend this way of setting up hierarquical data, as it is much faster to retrieve:

```
protected function formatJstree(){
        $categories = $this->descendants()->findAll();
        $level=0;
        $parent = 0;
        $data = array();
        foreach( $categories as $n => $category )
        {
            $node = array(
                'data'=> "{$category->title}",
                'attr'=>array('id'=>"category_id_{$category->category_id}")
            );
            if($category->level == $level){
                $data[$parent]["children"][] = $node;
            }
            else if($level != 0 && $category->level > $level){
                if(!isset($data[$n]["children"])){
                    $data[$n]["children"] = array();
                }
                $data[$parent]["children"][] = $node;
            }
            else
            {
                $data[] = $node;
                $parent = $n;
            }
            $level=$category->level;

        }
        return $data;

    }
```